# Simplified Java Library?

Tags: java

The majority of my problem is I don't know the exact working of what I'm trying to accomplish.

My friend and I are trying to write a Java game; I am familiar with Java/Python/C++ and he has only used Python (so no experience with classes and dot operators).

What I want to try to do is write some "importable library"(?) of sorts to help him out. A really, really simple example would be if he could type:

`print(String);`

and in the library there was some definition that `print(String)` = `System.out.println(String)`

Of course it would actually be more like `createGrass(coord_x, coord_y);` and then the createGrass would be actually reference a constructor with all the appropriate get/set methods.

I realize that I could just make a Landscape class and then he could use `Landscape.createGrass(...);` but I was hoping for something that wouldn't clutter up the work space and also something that I could just import into any project that would need similar work.

Thanks!

Comment: Python has both classes and the dot operator. And they're significantly more flexible than Java's.

Comment: My python coding knowledge only goes as far as my programming 101 class went, never had to use classes or dot operators.
Out of concern for time I was hoping there was a way I could help him out. Someone mentioned writing a parser but as you all can tell, I probably wouldn't be able to accomplish that. I was just hoping any of you more experienced programmers would have any ideas.

Comment: Although he could just use jython. its compatible with java I believe

Comment: I should have stopped reading after `he has only used Python (so no experience with classes)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a [static import](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html)?

```
// No promises this is compilable Java 
import static Landscape.createGrass;

public class Wtv {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        int coord_x = 4;
        int coord_y = 7;
        createGrass(coord_x, coord_y);
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't come across static imports before, I'll check them out.
Thank you very much.

Comment: +1 for teaching me something new